# Sending email using smtp (SSL) using port 465

Tags: wordpress, email, ssl, smtp, vps

I have a VPS server hosted by OVH with a wordpress running on apache. I purchased a private email server to namecheap but I can't make it work.
Here's the problem :
I put an add-on to use SMTP mail (wp smtp) on wordpress, I configured it with the right login in SSL mode and when I send a test message from the add-on it doesn't work for gmail receiver. It works for blabla@yopmail.com but not for blabla@someotherdomain.com. Usually when there's a problem an error is reported on the wp module, but here I get a success message. (and I checked the spam folder, nothing received).
Furthermore, I send a test message from the webmail provided by namecheap and it worked so the problem is on my side.
I use the port 465 with an SSL authentification and I have opened everything on iptables by entering these commands :

- iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
- iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
- iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
- iptables -F

The namecheap support said port 465 was closed, but don't know if this is the cause as I have turned off iptables. Maybe I forget to install something on the server ?

I'm lost and can't figure it out why it doesn't work.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

port 465 in SSL protocol 3 is referred as

> 465  Reserved (pending) for use by Simple Mail Transfer Protocol with
>   SSL (ssmtp).

refer : http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ssl/draft302.txt

but it is not registered to SMTPs https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0821.txt since it was never recognized by the **IETF (Internet Engineering Task Force)**
I recommend to use STARTTLS encryption on port 587